# Not able to run hive job as a oozie workflow in hue

Tags: oozie, hue, apache-hive

I am getting the following error when I have configured the simple hive job as a oozie workflow in hue

My Hive script file:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (a INT) STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/mapradm/input-data/table';
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/mapradm/output-data/hive' SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 5;
```

Input File (/user/mapradm/input-data/table):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Please provide me good solution for this

```
329-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@Hive] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [40000]
        2015-06-05 16:06:55,145  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - SERVER[c01n08.ss.sw.ericsson.se] USER[mapradm] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@Hive] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
        2015-06-05 16:06:55,178  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - SERVER[c01n08.ss.sw.ericsson.se] USER[mapradm] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@kill] Start action [0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
        2015-06-05 16:06:55,178  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - SERVER[c01n08.ss.sw.ericsson.se] USER[mapradm] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@kill] [***0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@kill***]Action status=DONE
        2015-06-05 16:06:55,178  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - SERVER[c01n08.ss.sw.ericsson.se] USER[mapradm] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@kill] [***0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W@kill***]Action updated in DB!
        2015-06-05 16:06:55,229  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - SERVER[c01n08.ss.sw.ericsson.se] USER[mapradm] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000029-150605105807329-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

Comment: You need to click on the log icon of the action of the Hive action in the workflow, it will print the logs with the real error message

Comment: it gives same info .., is there any sloution for this kind of exception

Comment: It should not, above are the Oozie logs, you need to look at the MapReduce logs. You are probably not using the good hive-site.xml or don't have the good HDFS permissions to write http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorials-ii-2-execute-hive-queries-and/